# Legendre Polynomials: proofs $\int_{-1}^1P_n^2(x)dx=\frac{2}{(2n+1)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

Does any one know, how to compute any of those two things?

> 1. The relationship between Legendre polynomials and Shifted Legendre Polynomials.
> 2. $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1P_n^2(x)dx=\dfrac{2}{(2n+1)}$ for $n\geq0$.

I tried to use Bonnet's equation:

$(2n-1)xP_{n-1}(x)=nP_n(x)+(n-1)P_{n-2}(x)$

but I couldn't move. Thanks :)

Edit: The second problem refers to regular Legendre Polynomials.

Comment: Are you sure Item 2 is written correctly? I assume that it is referring to the regular Legendre polynomials (not the shifted ones).

Comment: Yes, the second one reffers to regular ones. I'm sorry :/

Comment: I also think it should be $2/(2n+1)$ for item $2$. Can you check that?

Comment: Yea, sorry :/ my fault

Answer (score 3):

I will answer your question about determining the value of $\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x)^2dx$, using Rodrigues' formula
$$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^nn!}[(x^2-1)^n]^{(n)}$$

$\newcommand{\partial}[1]{\left[#1\right]}$
$\newcommand{\bracket}[1]{\left(#1\right)}$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I&=\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x)^2dx
\\ &=\frac{1}{2^{2n}n!^2}\int_{-1}^1 [(x^2-1)^n]^{(n)} \cdot [(x^2-1)^n]^{(n)}dx
\\ &=\frac{1}{2^{2n}n!^2} \bracket{\partial{[(x^2-1)^n]^{(n)}\cdot [(x^2-1)^n]^{(n-1)}}_{-1}^{+1}-\int_{-1}^1 [(x^2-1)^n]^{(n+1)}\cdot [(x^2-1)^n]^{(n-1)}dx}
\\ &=\frac{1}{2^{2n}n!^2} \bracket{0-\int_{-1}^1 [(x^2-1)^n]^{(n+1)}\cdot [(x^2-1)^n]^{(n-1)}dx}
\\ &=...
\\ &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}n!^2} \int_{-1}^1 [(x^2-1)^n]^{(2n)}\cdot [(x^2-1)^n]^{(0)}dx
\\ &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}n!^2} \cdot (2n)! \cdot \int_{-1}^1 (x^2-1)^ndx
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{-1}^1 (x^2-1)^ndx&=\int_{-1}^1 (x+1)^n(x-1)^ndx
\\ &=\bracket{\partial{\frac{(x+1)^{n+1}}{n+1}(x-1)^n}_{-1}^{+1} - \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(x+1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\cdot n(x-1)^{n-1}dx}
\\ &=\bracket{0 - \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(x+1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\cdot n(x-1)^{n-1}dx}
\\ &=...
\\ &=(-1)^n\int_{-1}^1 \frac{n!\cdot (x+1)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\cdot n!(x-1)^0dx
\\ &=(-1)^n\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}\int_{-1}^1 (x+1)^{2n}dx
\\ &=(-1)^n\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}\partial{\frac{(x+1)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}}_{-1}^{+1}
\\ &=(-1)^n\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}\cdot \frac{2^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So finally we get our desired value:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I&=\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x)^2dx
\\ &=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}n!^2} \cdot (2n)! \cdot (-1)^n\frac{n!^2}{(2n)!}\cdot \frac{2^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
\\ &=\frac{2}{2n+1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

**Part 1:**

See [*Shifted Legendre Polynomials*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials).

I am not exactly sure what you intend to do for part 1., since it is not clear from your question. Maybe you can clarify.

Look at the [*DLMF*](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.3) and what do you notice about the Legnedre versus SHifted Legendre. So, if you can prove one of them, do you see an approach to deriving the other?

**Part 2:**

Try evaluating the integral using [*Rodrigues' Formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula).

Comment: Thanks for your hints, what I'm asking in first question is, that there is a relation between them. I know about it. And you posted a wikipedia article talking about this. But I need a proof of this. And that's my problem. Thanks:)

Comment: See update - no more comments for a while

Comment: In the part 2 I'm supposed (forced) to use Bonnet's equation.

Comment: Then, you might be interested in the answers here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205932/problems-regarding-integrals-involving-legendre-polynomials

Comment: How did this go unvoted until now? +1

Comment: Don't I know it!

Comment: @amWhy: Yes, I have seen many of your nice answers get no or very low votes- but I'm working on that! :-)