# Legendre Polynomial Orthogonality and Size

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Show $(P_i,P_j)=\begin{cases} 0& i \neq j \\ \frac{2}{2j+1} & i = j\end{cases}$ for $0 \leq i, j\leq2$

I'm just not sure exactly what I'm supposed to do. Do I plug in values of i and j and solve?

Comment: do you mean Legendre polynomial?

Comment: second question - do you know the definition of the symbol $(P_i, P_j)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show the orthogonality relations of the first three [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) (not Lagrange):
$$P_0(x)=1,\quad P_1(x)=x,\quad P_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1),$$ where $(.,.)$ is defined as
$$(P_i,P_j) = \int_{-1}^{1}P_i(x)P_j(x) dx \,.$$
Here are two examples
$$(P_0,P_1) = \int_{-1}^{1}P_0(x)P_1(x)= \int_{-1}^{1}1\cdot xdx = \Big[\frac{x^2}{2}\Big]_{-1}^{1} = 0 $$
$$(P_1,P_1) = \int_{-1}^{1}x\cdot xdx =
\Big[\frac{x^3}{3}\Big]_{-1}^{1} = \frac{1}{3}-\frac{-1}{3}=\frac{2}{3} =\frac{2}{2\times 1 +1} $$
I guess you can now compute the remaining $(P_i,P_j).$

Answer (score 1):

Best directly solve it for all $i,j$.
Orthogonality of $P_i$ and $P_j$ when $i \not= j$ is easy; for instance use the fact that the Legendre equation is a special form of Sturm-Liouville equations.

For the second part, see my post on ([Legendre Polynomials: proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334524/legendre-polynomials-proofs/765168#765168)).