# Integrating Legendre's Polynomials

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, legendre-polynomials

I wanted to find the value of:
$$
\def\LegP{\operatorname{LegendreP}}
\int_{-1}^{1} \LegP[n, x] \frac{d}{dx} (\LegP[n+1,x]) \, dx.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{-1}^1 P_n P_{n+1}^{'}dx = \int_{-1}^1 P_n ((2n+1)P_n + P_{n-1}^{'})dx = (2n+1)\int_{-1}^1 P_n^2dx + \int_{-1}^1 P_n P_{n-1}^{'}dx $ = 2

Here I used the following:

$$(2n+1)P_n = P_{n+1}^{'} - P_{n-1}^{'}$$
$$\int_{-1}^1 P_n^2dx = \frac{2}{2n+1}$$
(see [Legendre Polynomials: proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334524/legendre-polynomials-proofs/765168#765168))

And the fact that $P_{n-1}^{'}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-2$ and thus can be expanded into a linear combination of $P_{n-2}$ to $P_0$, and $\int_{-1}^1 P_n P_m dx = 0$ if $m \ne n$